# Missing request - Pact python

Tags: python, api, rest, web-api-testing, pact

I'm new to pact and I've understood the concept but having hard time understanding and implementing the code.
Here I'm trying to do a simple pact for get_users from reqres.in.
I believe the first (pact ... code does the mock provider part and I compare that using the pact.json file.

```
import os
import requests
import pytest
from pact import Consumer, Provider, Format
import unittest
import json


pact = Consumer('Consumer').has_pact_with(Provider('Provider'), port=1234, host_name='localhost')
pact.start_service()

CURR_FILE_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
PACT_DIR = os.path.join(CURR_FILE_PATH, '')
PACT_FILE = os.path.join(PACT_DIR, 'pact.json')

#defining class
class GetUsers(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get_board(self):
        with open(os.path.join(PACT_DIR, PACT_FILE), 'rb') as path_file:
            pact_file_json = json.load(path_file)
            print('pact_json')

            (pact
                .given('Request to send message')
                .upon_receiving('a request for response or send message')
                .with_request(method = 'GET', path = '/api/users?page=2')
                .will_respond_with(status = 200, body = pact_file_json))

            with pact:
                result = requests.get('http://reqres.in/api/users?page=2')
                print('actual response')

            self.assertEqual(pact_file_json, result.json())
            pact.verify()


ge = GetUsers()
print(ge.test_get_board())
```

however, when I run the code, I get the following error

1. the data do not match but I verified it in another code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Pact\contract_test.py", line 41, in <module>
    print(ge.test_get_board())
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Pact\contract_test.py", line 34, in test_get_board
    print(data)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pact\pact.py", line 370, in __exit__
    self.verify()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pact\pact.py", line 269, in verify
    assert resp.status_code == 200, resp.text
AssertionError: Actual interactions do not match expected interactions for mock MockService.
```

2. says missing requests

```
Missing requests:
    GET https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2
```

Comment: @MatthewFellows

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to attempt here - why are you opening up a `pact.json` file in this context? The consumer pact package will automatically serialise any contracts if successful, and you don't seem to be reading the file in anywhere.

The second problem seems to be that some code somewhere, is issuing (or requesting?) the query string `page=2` but the code you've shown doesn't make use of any query strings.

Could you have another mock service running somewhere?

**Examples**

- https://docs.pactflow.io/docs/examples/python/consumer/readme
- https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-python/blob/master/examples/e2e/tests/consumer/test_user_consumer.py

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the code now, I looked up a lot but didn't find a working example to implement PACT using python, I believe the mock provider should return the expected response, and we give the mock provider the expected response via the pact_json_file, Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. It's a lot to ask but please modify the code to work on a GET method from reqres.in. Thanks for your time and help

Comment: I've added two examples you could use.  You don't need to pass in a JSON file (you can, but you don't need to), but you do need to tell the mock service what you expect.